# Strange behaviour in C Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *ptr,a=10;
ptr=&a;

printf("%d %d",*ptr,a); // 10 10

printf("\n\n%d %d",*ptr,a++); //11 10

printf("\n\n%d %d",a++, *ptr); //11 12

printf("\n\n%d %d",a, *ptr); //12 12
```

My question is in the second printf. Why *ptr and a is different?

Comment: This is not a dublicate of the linked questions. One of them is about accessing the same variable twice, without pointers, and the other one is a C++ question.

Comment: Using a variable twice in the same statement, that has a increment or decrement, even when the other access it dereferencing a pointer, is UB.